# unresolved symbol trouble

Tags: c++

I have the following project files:

```
//connections.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "LibraryHeaders.h"
#include "FileManager.h"

#define WSAVersion 0x202
#define GSMsgID 0x100

extern HWND Main_hWnd;

bool InitConnections ()
{
    FileManager::ConnectFile *connectfile = FileManager::ReadConnectFile(connectfile);
    SockBase GSConnection(WSAVersion, TCP, connectfile->GS_IP, connectfile->GS_Port, Main_hWnd, GSMsgID);
    if (GSConnection.Connect() != true) {return false;}
    return true;
}

//FileManager.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "FileManager.h"
#include "LibraryHeaders.h"

using namespace FileManager;

ConnectFile* ReadConnectFile(ConnectFile *ConnectStruct)
{
    FileLibrary connectfile("DMOConnection.cfg");
    if (connectfile.OpenFile(HEAP, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE, PAGE_READWRITE) != true) {return false;}
    ConnectStruct->GS_IP = connectfile.parser->str_GetToken((char*)connectfile.FileBuff);
    if (ConnectStruct->GS_IP == (const char*) -1) {return false;}
    ConnectStruct->GS_Port = connectfile.parser->int_GetToken((char*)connectfile.FileBuff);
    if (ConnectStruct->GS_Port == -1) {return false;}
    return ConnectStruct;
}

//FileManager.h
namespace FileManager
{
    struct ConnectFile
    {
        const char* GS_IP;
        unsigned int GS_Port;
    };

    ConnectFile* ReadConnectFile(ConnectFile*);
}
```

And when trying to build the project i got this error:

```
Connections.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct FileManager::ConnectFile * __cdecl FileManager::ReadConnectFile(struct FileManager::ConnectFile *)" (?ReadConnectFile@FileManager@@YAPAUConnectFile@1@PAU21@@Z) referenced in function "bool __cdecl InitConnections(void)" (?InitConnections@@YA_NXZ)
```

I dont understand why, the linker should look up and see that ive defined FileManager::ReadConnectFile on FileManager.cpp but it doesnt, any tip how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You're defining a free function:

```
ConnectFile* ReadConnectFile(ConnectFile *ConnectStruct)
```

not a member:

```
ConnectFile* FileManager::ReadConnectFile(ConnectFile *ConnectStruct)
```

Totally different.

Also:

```
using namespace FileManager;
```

and

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct FileManager::ConnectFile [...]

suggests you have a `namespace FileManager` and a `struct FileManager`... any reason for using the same name?

Comment: mmm i dont have any struct called FileManager only the one called "ConnectFile" wich is part of the FileManager namespace... also i dont get it about defining a free function :/

Comment: @user1175832 try reproducing the problem on ideone.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by declaring the function out of the namespace:

```
namespace FileManager
{
    struct ConnectFile
    {
        const char* GS_IP;
        unsigned int GS_Port;
    };
}

using namespace FileManager;
ConnectFile* ReadConnectFile(ConnectFile *ConnectStruct);
```

The IDE is VC11 Beta, thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

The code

`using namespace FileManager;

ConnectFile* ReadConnectFile(ConnectFile *ConnectStruct)

{ ...some definition...}`

defines the ReadConnectFile function **not** in the namespace FileManager, but in global namespace.